# Is self a keyword in python?

Tags: python

I Tried to answer but i  have written  something wrong.
I tried to answer but I written something wrong or may be I am doing something out of this question syllabus and i want a full descriptive type of answer of this question in which its uses and working has been derived.

Answer (score 2):

No, `self` is not a keyword. It is the first argument of methods by convention, but you can use any name you like instead, and freely use `self` as a variable name elsewhere.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: No. I learned something. Self is not a keyword. [Self is just a conventional name for the first argument of a method](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=self#what-is-self). The more you know...

Indeed. Self is a keyword to create and evocate the class itself. You should not use self in your code if is not to autoreferenciate it's own class, or funny things will happen.

Comment: [`self` is not a keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)